# boost and gcc&make - compiler and version agnostic linking

Tags: gcc, boost, makefile

Boost jam creates fancy static library names such as `boost_system-mgw45-mt-d-1_44`, which contain compiler and library version.
Let's assume that I want to distribute application in sources buildable with standard makefile, and user should install The Boost library himself. 
Is there any well known ways to determine installed compiler and library versions to compose static library names?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `autoconf` and use the various `AX_BOOST_` macros, if you check the autoconf-archive. (The archive is often available from your package manager, I know debian and macports have it). If you also use `automake`, then setting `--install` in `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` will copy the macro definitions into your project.

Comment: https://github.com/tsuna/boost.m4 is the best way to get Boost support with autoconf.  Better than the autoconf macro archive utilities.

Comment: I'm quite new to Autotools, so here's one more silly question. To use results of configure script I obligatory need to use automake? I didn't find any environment variables set (using tsuna's boost.m4).

Comment: @Andrew: No. `automake` requires `autoconf`, but you can use `autoconf` to substitute values discovered by configure into other templates, too. See this tutorial: http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~adl/autotools.html